# Traceback (most recent call last) OSerror and font not found

Tags: kivy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb8yO.jpg)i will run python script with kivy and kivymd but this problem appears, how to solve it?  I already installed the kivy library and kivymd still looks like this...

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
def build(self):
return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()

Traceback (most last): File "d:/Python/main python/main.py", line 2, in  from kivy.uix.label import Label File "C:\Users\andihasan AppData\Local\Programs\  Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\labe 1.py", line 286, in  from kivy.core.text import Label as Corelabel, DEFAULT_FONT File "C:\Users\andihasan AppData  \Local\Programs \Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\tex t_init_-py", line 1013, in  Label.register(DEFAULT_FONT, **default_font_paths) File "C: \Users\  andihasanAppData\Local\Programs \Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\coreltex t_init*_-py", line 315, in register raise IOError('File {e} not found'.format(font_type)) OSError:  File data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf not found

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OSError: File data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf not found.

This line is the cause of your error.
if you're trying to use custom fonts in your kivymd project, you need to have the font file. that is the .ttf file
and to use the font without having to put the full directory, you need to register the font with the following lines.

first import label base

```
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
```

then register the font with an easier name to refer to.

```
if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    LabelBase.register(name="RobotoReg", fn_regular="{full_path_to}/Roboto-Regular.ttf")
```

you can then use it in your .kv file like so:

```
MDLabel:
    text: "Text to test if font name works"
    size_hint_x: 1
    pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y": .5}
    font_name: "RobotoReg"
    font_style: "Caption"
    halign: "center"
```

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work, is there any other solution?

Comment: do you still receive the same error. or the error is fixed but the fond does not work. either ways I need to see what we are working.

Comment: I tried the test kivy code below

Comment: from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello, World")


MainApp().run()

Comment: For some reason, if this code gave you an error then, it is most definitely your OS or your installation of kivy. i just ran the code on my mac OS and it ran without a hitch. consider reinstalling the kivy or switch to kivymd.

Comment: actually I'm still confused to make a kv file, I want to send a screenshot but can't, can I send it through your Instagram?

Comment: you can send a screenshot in your question edit that should be possible or better still, edit the question with the full code. both your python code and kv code

Comment: I've edited it friend, now you can see the screenshot and the code